# Zombienet: How to confirm if my parachain is producing blocks?

Tags: parachain, docker, parachain-collator, zombienet, kubernetes

I ran my Zombienet network(it is like a Docker + Kubernetes network)

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

then I got:

```
{
  name: 'alice',
  key: '2bd806c97f0e00af1a1fc3328fa763a9269723c8db8fac4f93af71db186d6e90',
  accounts: {
    seed: '0xd869434a3250ac5335282ebb066439bebcba7083ecc4c43ba05be7c3f6698e66',
    sr_account: {
      address: '5HMYBmVcRGdYMRkVjcmxX5YZpLVzE8ZmP3xCoZYXNaVbRsZq',
      publicKey: '0xea03c8debdaa066df36a735a5dd5717dbb2faab28230f7b054332e67feaafb71'
    },
    sr_stash: {
      address: '5HEGXSoZGCkj1dYC1VLKEfd1tU7c9SyyiDcT7HHC4n9AWfnh',
      publicKey: '0xe478591d869859a831b8512a77ab460ebdce1f616eb1cb980ffa969adf02e74e'
    },
    ed_account: {
      address: '5GV4ZA5AEPGMgCsLw2TQsLWGPFPhvT1kcDaB1VMiZDVJpL4N',
      publicKey: '0xc3847fdc4bf1de208fc17bb28b306a0cb2ce89b5a0fcf2534dedab5829e2a38e'
    },
    ec_account: { publicKey: [Uint8Array] }
  },
  command: 'polkadot',
  commandWithArgs: undefined,
  image: 'docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master',
  chain: 'rococo-local',
  validator: true,
  args: [ '-lparachain=debug' ],
  env: [
    { name: 'COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN', value: '1' },
    { name: 'RUST_BACKTRACE', value: 'FULL' }
  ],
  bootnodes: [],
  telemetryUrl: '',
  telemetry: false,
  prometheus: true,
  overrides: [],
  addToBootnodes: false,
  resources: undefined,
  zombieRole: 'node',
  group: 'alice'
}
{
  name: 'bob',
  key: '81b637d8fcd2c6da6359e6963113a1170de795e4b725b84d1e0b4cfd9ec58ce9',
  accounts: {
    seed: '0x443d46a876ce317f69d2bbf49c5e255ce6cb43e6e232bc02035e9c34def27ec4',
    sr_account: {
      address: '5DM6hvELqvDjxCLLX6hQAn9scZp7dMfz4WDurdXLHP1j9JLh',
      publicKey: '0x38bd13b42103a39b6a336026528477496e0ddf0174efcf58fadf67271b85ff4d'
    },
    sr_stash: {
      address: '5GKbySSE8rm1QE5XPYgK1ewFM4nKQCrW1RWUnXdGReDQBe64',
      publicKey: '0xbc4dcf5ec9aebce67682272c7c3a44fb26b767081e9cf399544cd06ec8c8b837'
    },
    ed_account: {
      address: '5CqGupTU73eR3qvwocZuG1oQiqNdrUE7Rqfmc3MGCTG2FnNy',
      publicKey: '0x21fe118b89a8271d4e4843cb82063271a3cd1e297bd40f95c92f44a6414c1353'
    },
    ec_account: { publicKey: [Uint8Array] }
  },
  command: 'polkadot',
  commandWithArgs: undefined,
  image: 'docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master',
  chain: 'rococo-local',
  validator: true,
  args: [ '-lparachain=debug' ],
  env: [
    { name: 'COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN', value: '1' },
    { name: 'RUST_BACKTRACE', value: 'FULL' }
  ],
  bootnodes: [],
  telemetryUrl: '',
  telemetry: false,
  prometheus: true,
  overrides: [],
  addToBootnodes: false,
  resources: undefined,
  zombieRole: 'node',
  group: 'bob'
}

     Using provider: kubernetes

     Launching network under namespace: zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c
         Using temporary directory: /tmp/zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c_-102217-SLT1Ct5M9Foj

    launching temp pod with image docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master
         with command: bash -c polkadot build-spec --chain rococo-local --disable-default-bootnode > /cfg/rococo-local-plain.json && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
        temp pod is ready!

         Starting with a fresh authority set...
               Added Genesis Authority alice - 5HEGXSoZGCkj1dYC1VLKEfd1tU7c9SyyiDcT7HHC4n9AWfnh
               Added Genesis Authority bob - 5GKbySSE8rm1QE5XPYgK1ewFM4nKQCrW1RWUnXdGReDQBe64

    launching temp-collator pod with image docker.io/paritypr/colander:master
         with command: bash -c adder-collator export-genesis-state > /cfg/genesis-state && adder-collator export-genesis-wasm > /cfg/genesis-wasm && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
        temp-collator pod is ready!

          ✓ Added Genesis Parachain 2000

    launching temp-1 pod with image docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master
         with command: bash -c polkadot build-spec --chain /cfg/rococo-local-plain.json --disable-default-bootnode  --raw > /cfg/rococo-local-raw.json && until [ -f /tmp/finished.txt ]; do echo waiting for copy files to finish; sleep 1; done; echo copy files has finished
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c_-102217-SLT1Ct5M9Foj/rococo-local-plain.json as:e31d2cda9a8785e584c5b0bed336da58618176307b3bb53b0c241b3e80544a36
        temp-1 pod is ready!

         Chain name: Rococo Local Testnet

         ⚙ Clear Boot Nodes

    launching alice pod with image docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh polkadot --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name alice --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external -lparachain=debug --no-mdns --node-key 2bd806c97f0e00af1a1fc3328fa763a9269723c8db8fac4f93af71db186d6e90 --no-telemetry --prometheus-external --jaeger-agent localhost:6831 --validator --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c_-102217-SLT1Ct5M9Foj/rococo-local.json as:081528097115e26a72d41d35423d9744ffe250e4eef578ed5452644ba707919e
uploading to fileserver: /tmp/zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c_-102217-SLT1Ct5M9Foj/zombie-wrapper.sh as:8b5c6315d5cdcb7c3ead670c78cdc3f54046241497b55b16177aae09b22a10b7
        alice pod is ready!
    alice running

         You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

             kubectl logs -f alice

         ⚙ Added Boot Nodes:  /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm

    launching bob pod with image docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh polkadot --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name bob --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external -lparachain=debug --no-mdns --node-key 81b637d8fcd2c6da6359e6963113a1170de795e4b725b84d1e0b4cfd9ec58ce9 --no-telemetry --prometheus-external --jaeger-agent localhost:6831 --validator --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
        bob pod is ready!
    bob running

         You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

             kubectl logs -f bob
     All relay chain nodes spawned...

    launching collator01 pod with image docker.io/paritypr/colander:master
         with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh adder-collator --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name collator01 --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --no-mdns --node-key 5e123980fad4770d9ab5b7df7bbee8499943822a8555d11995e8203210065342 --no-telemetry --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
        collator01 pod is ready!
    collator01 running

 You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 
             kubectl logs -f collator01
Warn: Tracing collator service doesn't exist
---------------------------
Network launched 
     In namespace zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c with kubernetes provider
     Node name: alice
     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A36465#/explorer
     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:40949/metrics
---
     Node name: bob
     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A44789#/explorer
     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:40163/metrics
---
Parachain ID: 2000
     Node name: collator01
     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46485#/explorer
     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:38445/metrics
```

I tried `kubectl logs -f collator01` in another terminal, then I got `Error from server (NotFound): pods "collator01" not found`

How can I get this collator01's logs?

When I clicked on the Parachain collator link https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A46485#/explorer

under Network > Explorer > Node Info: I saw 2 peers

```
12D3KooWRkZhiRhsqmrQ28rt73K7V3aCBpqKrLGSXmZ99PTcTZby    authority   130 0xad3a492a22e12ff865fea93f3e3e44df8dbb8ffd9559749f8a0569062cd2a7bf
12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm    authority   130 0xad3a492a22e12ff865fea93f3e3e44df8dbb8ffd9559749f8a0569062cd2a7bf
```

`12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm` matches relaychain node Alice as Added Boot Nodes:  `/ip4/172.17.0.6/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm`

under Network > Parachains:

```
parachains                lifecycle     included    backed  timeout chain   in/out  leases
2,000                                 Parachain
Val. Group 0 (1)
5HEGXS…9AWfnh (0)
Non-voters (0)
```

Does this prove my parachain 2000 is properly registered ?

under Network > Explorer > ChainInfo, I saw many blocks were being produced:

```
recent blocks
397  0xf5c6e28b506171ea78940d1708ea37c5624f64a997f3fd5f3341f11034345fb1  5HEGXS…9AWfnh
396  0x2249d6ba127e3369c21c58e56e6b1f4dff385eb6f908e0ba7c4c415f1958b50d  5GKbyS…DQBe64
```

5HEGXS…9AWfnh and 5GKbyS…DQBe64 match what I had in my command line logs:

```
 Starting with a fresh authority set...
       Added Genesis Authority alice - 5HEGXSoZGCkj1dYC1VLKEfd1tU7c9SyyiDcT7HHC4n9AWfnh
       Added Genesis Authority bob - 5GKbySSE8rm1QE5XPYgK1ewFM4nKQCrW1RWUnXdGReDQBe64
```

Does this prove my parachain is producing blocks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes looks like the parachain is producing blocks. Also, I will fix the `tail logs command` asap and draft a new release.

For reference, in this case should be

```
kubectl logs -f collator01 -c collator01 -n zombie-aa3f81ef14a3fc7592ca0cc07309f72c
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I used that command and found parachain id value is fixed!?? please have a look: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/zombienet-test-fails-after-changing-parachain-id