# Zombienet: test fails after changing parachain id

Tags: parachain, collator, parachain-collator, zombienet

Originally I had this network definition file:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/paritypr/polkadot-debug:master"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 100

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

and my test file:

```
Description: Small Network test
Network: ./z01-small-network.toml
Creds: config

# well know functions
alice: is up
bob: is up
alice: parachain 100 is registered within 225 seconds

# logs
bob: log line matches glob "*rted #1*" within 10 seconds
bob: log line matches "Imported #[0-9]+" within 10 seconds
bob: log line matches "Imported new block." within 10 seconds

alice: parachain 100 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds

# Tracing
# alice: trace with traceID 94c1501a78a0d83c498cc92deec264d9 contains ["answer-chunk-request", "answer-chunk-request"]

# metrics
alice: reports node_roles is 4
alice: reports sub_libp2p_is_major_syncing is 0

# histogram
#alice: reports histogram polkadot_pvf_execution_time has at least 2 samples in buckets ["0.1", "0.25", "0.5", "+Inf"] within 100 seconds

# system events
bob: system event contains "A candidate was included" within 20 seconds
alice: system event matches glob "*was backed*" within 10 seconds
```

The test ran successfully.

Then I changed the parachain id from 100 to 2000 in my network definition file:

```
[[parachains]]
id = 2000
```

and changed it in my test file

```
alice: parachain 2000 is registered within 225 seconds
alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds
```

then block height test failed !!!??? What happened?

```
    ✔ alice: is up (159ms)
    ✔ bob: is up (93ms)
2022-05-12 21:43:44        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead, mmr_generateBatchProof, state_trieMigrationStatus
    ✔ alice: parachain 2000 is registered within 225 seconds (3035ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches glob "*rted #1*" within 10 seconds (194ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported #[0-9]+" within 10 seconds (195ms)
    ✔ bob: log line matches "Imported new block." within 10 seconds (123ms)

     Error:  
         Timeout(150), "getting desired parachain block height 6 within 150 secs".

    1) alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds
    ✔ alice: reports node_roles is 4
    ✔ alice: reports sub_libp2p_is_major_syncing is 0
2022-05-12 21:46:18        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead, mmr_generateBatchProof, state_trieMigrationStatus
    2) bob: system event contains "A candidate was included" within 20 seconds
2022-05-12 21:46:38        API/INIT: RPC methods not decorated: beefy_getFinalizedHead, mmr_generateBatchProof, state_trieMigrationStatus
    3) alice: system event matches glob "*was backed*" within 10 seconds

     Node's logs are available in /tmp/zombie-540455ef8ad2e803ca8f34df7aba359c_-267460-xyaOcnkB7UwG/logs

     Deleting network
2022-05-12 21:46:48        RPC-CORE: health(): Health:: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:41881: 1000:: Normal connection closure
2022-05-12 21:46:55        RPC-CORE: getStorage(key: StorageKey, at?: BlockHash): StorageData:: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:41881: 1006:: Connection dropped by remote peer.
2022-05-12 21:46:55        RPC-CORE: health(): Health:: disconnected from ws://127.0.0.1:41881: 1006:: Connection dropped by remote peer.
child process exited


  8 passing (6m)
  3 failing

  1) small network( Small Network test )
       alice: parachain 2000 block height is at least 6 within 150 seconds:

      AssertionError: expected 0 to be at least 6
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +6
      
      at /snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:265:37
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:24:58)

  2) small network( Small Network test )
       bob: system event contains "A candidate was included" within 20 seconds:
     AssertionError: expected false to be truthy
      at /snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:367:32
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:24:58)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:497:9)

  3) small network( Small Network test )
       alice: system event matches glob "*was backed*" within 10 seconds:
     AssertionError: expected false to be truthy
      at /snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:367:32
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/snapshot/zombienet/dist/test-runner/index.js:24:58)
```

What is wrong?

I think I got some clues from the collor01 log:

```
kubectl logs -f collator01 -c collator01 -n zombie-540455ef8...
```

The collator logs:

```
2022-05-12 13:43:53  Highest known block at #0    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=0.0.0.0:9933, allowed origins=None    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944, allowed origins=None    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 Running adder collator for parachain id: 100    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 Genesis state: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011b4d03dd8c01f1049143cf9c4c817e4b167f1d1b83e5c6f0f10d89ba1e7bce    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 Validation code: 0x52bc537646db8e0528b52ffd
```

Can you see `parachain id: 100` from above log? ... That is not correct! It should have been 2000!

Then the logs continue:

```
2022-05-12 13:43:53  New epoch 0 launching at block 0x71a4…bf72 (block slot 275393835 >= start slot 275393835).    
2022-05-12 13:43:53  Next epoch starts at slot 275393845    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 ParentBlockRandomness did not provide entropy    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 ✨ Imported #1 (0x71a4…bf72)    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 ✨ Imported #2 (0xbdb6…88d8)    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 ✨ Imported #3 (0xd762…e188)    
2022-05-12 13:43:53 ✨ Imported #4 (0x3d10…f120)    
2022-05-12 13:43:54 ✨ Imported #5 (0x829d…0813)    
2022-05-12 13:43:58  Idle (2 peers), best: #5 (0x829d…0813), finalized #2 (0xbdb6…88d8), ⬇ 4.1kiB/s ⬆ 3.1kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:00 ✨ Imported #6 (0xf678…876a)    
2022-05-12 13:44:03  Idle (2 peers), best: #6 (0xf678…876a), finalized #2 (0xbdb6…88d8), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:06 ✨ Imported #7 (0x52b3…2894)    
2022-05-12 13:44:08  Idle (2 peers), best: #7 (0x52b3…2894), finalized #4 (0x3d10…f120), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:12 ✨ Imported #8 (0x67d0…b6ea)    
2022-05-12 13:44:13  Idle (2 peers), best: #8 (0x67d0…b6ea), finalized #4 (0x3d10…f120), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:18 ✨ Imported #9 (0x3fa7…f515)    
2022-05-12 13:44:18 ✨ Imported #9 (0x802e…c090)    
2022-05-12 13:44:18  Idle (2 peers), best: #9 (0x3fa7…f515), finalized #5 (0x829d…0813), ⬇ 1.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:23  Idle (2 peers), best: #9 (0x3fa7…f515), finalized #6 (0xf678…876a), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:24 ✨ Imported #10 (0x2141…a0f2)    
2022-05-12 13:44:28  Idle (2 peers), best: #10 (0x2141…a0f2), finalized #6 (0xf678…876a), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:30  New epoch 1 launching at block 0x79b1…6fe6 (block slot 275393845 >= start slot 275393845).    
2022-05-12 13:44:30  Next epoch starts at slot 275393855    
2022-05-12 13:44:30 ✨ Imported #11 (0x79b1…6fe6)    
2022-05-12 13:44:30 Advanced session window for approvals update=Advanced { prev_window_start: 0, prev_window_end: 0, new_window_start: 0, new_window_end: 1 }
2022-05-12 13:44:33  Idle (2 peers), best: #11 (0x79b1…6fe6), finalized #8 (0x67d0…b6ea), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:36 ✨ Imported #12 (0x5d1b…193a)    
2022-05-12 13:44:38  Idle (2 peers), best: #12 (0x5d1b…193a), finalized #9 (0x3fa7…f515), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:42 ✨ Imported #13 (0x2bbe…b677)    
2022-05-12 13:44:43  Idle (2 peers), best: #13 (0x2bbe…b677), finalized #9 (0x3fa7…f515), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:48 ✨ Imported #14 (0xe1fd…55f4)    
2022-05-12 13:44:48  Idle (2 peers), best: #14 (0xe1fd…55f4), finalized #10 (0x2141…a0f2), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:53  Idle (2 peers), best: #14 (0xe1fd…55f4), finalized #10 (0x2141…a0f2), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:44:54 ✨ Imported #15 (0xef73…58aa)    
2022-05-12 13:44:58  Idle (2 peers), best: #15 (0xef73…58aa), finalized #12 (0x5d1b…193a), ⬇ 1.0kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:00 ✨ Imported #16 (0xe38e…e485)    
2022-05-12 13:45:03  Idle (2 peers), best: #16 (0xe38e…e485), finalized #13 (0x2bbe…b677), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:06 ✨ Imported #17 (0xa379…9ad5)    
2022-05-12 13:45:08  Idle (2 peers), best: #17 (0xa379…9ad5), finalized #13 (0x2bbe…b677), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:12 ✨ Imported #18 (0x6eaf…c841)    
2022-05-12 13:45:13  Idle (2 peers), best: #18 (0x6eaf…c841), finalized #14 (0xe1fd…55f4), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:18 ✨ Imported #19 (0x0359…55b3)    
2022-05-12 13:45:18  Idle (2 peers), best: #19 (0x0359…55b3), finalized #16 (0xe38e…e485), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:23  Idle (2 peers), best: #19 (0x0359…55b3), finalized #16 (0xe38e…e485), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:24 ✨ Imported #20 (0x247a…3829)    
2022-05-12 13:45:28  Idle (2 peers), best: #20 (0x247a…3829), finalized #17 (0xa379…9ad5), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:30  New epoch 2 launching at block 0xa37b…ff93 (block slot 275393855 >= start slot 275393855).    
2022-05-12 13:45:30  Next epoch starts at slot 275393865    
2022-05-12 13:45:30 ✨ Imported #21 (0xa37b…ff93)    
2022-05-12 13:45:30 Advanced session window for approvals update=Advanced { prev_window_start: 0, prev_window_end: 1, new_window_start: 0, new_window_end: 2 }
2022-05-12 13:45:33  Idle (2 peers), best: #21 (0xa37b…ff93), finalized #17 (0xa379…9ad5), ⬇ 0.9kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:36 ✨ Imported #22 (0xa43c…2cac)    
2022-05-12 13:45:38  Idle (2 peers), best: #22 (0xa43c…2cac), finalized #18 (0x6eaf…c841), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:42 ✨ Imported #23 (0x4cfd…b4da)    
2022-05-12 13:45:42 ✨ Imported #23 (0x068d…70fe)    
2022-05-12 13:45:43  Idle (2 peers), best: #23 (0x4cfd…b4da), finalized #20 (0x247a…3829), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:48 ✨ Imported #24 (0xb9b6…778e)    
2022-05-12 13:45:48  Idle (2 peers), best: #24 (0xb9b6…778e), finalized #20 (0x247a…3829), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:49  Applying authority set change scheduled at block #21    
2022-05-12 13:45:49  Applying GRANDPA set change to new set [(Public(a40f9c22185e85da8b7bd994b4305dbdab004da2288cc77061cb216bb264f0cc (5FmpM6me...)), 1), (Public(e922806258d9c1257d168f05bdbaa87e33c0e90bc38803c9af6c56dbf0206898 (5HLPGEGr...)), 1)]    
2022-05-12 13:45:53  Idle (2 peers), best: #24 (0xb9b6…778e), finalized #21 (0xa37b…ff93), ⬇ 0.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:45:54 ✨ Imported #25 (0x4d0f…3ccb)    
2022-05-12 13:45:58  Idle (2 peers), best: #25 (0x4d0f…3ccb), finalized #22 (0xa43c…2cac), ⬇ 0.8kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:00 ✨ Imported #26 (0xc6a3…c6cf)    
2022-05-12 13:46:03  Idle (2 peers), best: #26 (0xc6a3…c6cf), finalized #22 (0xa43c…2cac), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:06 ✨ Imported #27 (0xae85…8571)    
2022-05-12 13:46:08  Idle (2 peers), best: #27 (0xae85…8571), finalized #24 (0xb9b6…778e), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:12 ✨ Imported #28 (0x9d19…13c4)    
2022-05-12 13:46:13  Idle (2 peers), best: #28 (0x9d19…13c4), finalized #24 (0xb9b6…778e), ⬇ 0.7kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:18 ✨ Imported #29 (0xf8c2…4e06)    
2022-05-12 13:46:18 ✨ Imported #29 (0x59aa…25c4)    
2022-05-12 13:46:18  Idle (2 peers), best: #29 (0xf8c2…4e06), finalized #25 (0x4d0f…3ccb), ⬇ 1.3kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:23  Idle (2 peers), best: #29 (0xf8c2…4e06), finalized #26 (0xc6a3…c6cf), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 0.2kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:24 ✨ Imported #30 (0x1299…4771)    
2022-05-12 13:46:28  Idle (2 peers), best: #30 (0x1299…4771), finalized #26 (0xc6a3…c6cf), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:30  New epoch 3 launching at block 0x0c6a…262c (block slot 275393865 >= start slot 275393865).    
2022-05-12 13:46:30  Next epoch starts at slot 275393875    
2022-05-12 13:46:30 ✨ Imported #31 (0x0c6a…262c)    
2022-05-12 13:46:30 Advanced session window for approvals update=Advanced { prev_window_start: 0, prev_window_end: 2, new_window_start: 0, new_window_end: 3 }
2022-05-12 13:46:33  Idle (2 peers), best: #31 (0x0c6a…262c), finalized #28 (0x9d19…13c4), ⬇ 1.0kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:36 ✨ Imported #32 (0x0e5a…2db8)    
2022-05-12 13:46:38  Idle (2 peers), best: #32 (0x0e5a…2db8), finalized #29 (0xf8c2…4e06), ⬇ 1.0kiB/s ⬆ 0.4kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:42 ✨ Imported #33 (0x9cd3…0317)    
2022-05-12 13:46:42 ✨ Imported #33 (0x0f64…393a)    
2022-05-12 13:46:43  Idle (2 peers), best: #33 (0x9cd3…0317), finalized #29 (0xf8c2…4e06), ⬇ 1.2kiB/s ⬆ 0.5kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:48 ♻️  Reorg on #33,0x9cd3…0317 to #34,0x8365…1cb9, common ancestor #32,0x0e5a…2db8    
2022-05-12 13:46:48 ✨ Imported #34 (0x8365…1cb9)    
2022-05-12 13:46:48  Idle (2 peers), best: #34 (0x8365…1cb9), finalized #30 (0x1299…4771), ⬇ 0.6kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:53  Idle (2 peers), best: #34 (0x8365…1cb9), finalized #30 (0x1299…4771), ⬇ 0.3kiB/s ⬆ 0.3kiB/s    
2022-05-12 13:46:53  Applying authority set change scheduled at block #31
```

I can see `Imported #33` so the parachain collator had been producing many blocks.

So why the block height test failed???

I am using the latest zombienet-linux  v1.2.32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/decdbedea6d49b0604fee3241970a7ff383fe1db/parachain/test-parachains/adder/collator/src/main.rs#L87

If there is none provided via the CLI, the adder collator will assume `100` as default.

Note that `adder-collator` is the utmost basic collator one can imagine, it should only be used for basic smoke tests.

Comment: As @drahnr says you need to provide the parachain-id through the cli, I just put a working config and test for parachain-2000 in the gh issue (https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/193#issuecomment-1125314298).
Thanks!

Comment: I see to add `args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]` Thank you!

Comment: See also https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/203

Answer (score 1):

From version `v1.2.34`, `parachain-id` argument is handled automatically by zombienet so this configuration should works as expected.

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line: `args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]` so network definition file:

```
[relaychain]
default_image = "docker.io/parity/polkadot:v0.9.18"
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "docker.io/paritypr/colander:master"
  command = "adder-collator"
  args = ["--parachain-id 2000"]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

Comment: Hi @Russo, I just push a change draft a new release `v1.2.34` where you don't need to set the `parachain-id` argument anymore.
Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: It works! Thank you :)